# Multi-thread for loop by cuda

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I would like to make a for loop that tests 2^41 value with cuda.
I wrote this piece of code, but it tests the same key several times, but I would like to test it only once and I don't know why.

```
__global__ void kernel(int fileSize, unsigned char * buffer)
{
   for(mot64 i3 = 0L; i3 < (1L << 41); i3++){
     deCipher(buffer, i3, fileSize);
   }
   return;
}
```

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: What exactly is surprising to you here? The kernel function is run by every thread you launch. So, as written in your kernel function, every thread will loop through the values from 0 to 2^41 - 1. If you want each thread to test different values, then you have to write the loop in such a way that each thread will test different values…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to not really understand the basics of how massively parallel GPU computing works so I'll try my best to give you a "quick" explanation of what's going on. But really, you'll wanna read some good book about it because this is a massive and complicated subject.

When launching a kernel in CUDA, you're launching it to run on a specific number of threads, like this:

```
kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(fileSize, buffer);
```

This means that the function will run on a specified number of `blocks`, and each block has a certain number of `threads`, for a total of `blocks*threads` threads.

To really understand what this means you need to read some book about CUDA and what grids, blocks and threads are. A simple explanation is that a function is launched on a "`grid`". This "`grid`" is divided in "`blocks`". Think about these blocks as virtual "cores" in a CPU. Not really correct but close enough to have a vague idea of what we're talking about. Each "`block`" is itself divided into "`threads`". Each of thses "`threads`" is running your function independently. So you now have your function running a massive amount of instances in parallel. You want each instance to access a different portion of your buffer.

Inside your kernel, you wanna calculate which thread you're working on like this:

```
int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
```

[This image is very important.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Block-thread.svg)

As you can see, the grid is two dimensional, and the two dimensions are conveniently called `x` and `y`. Think about rows and columns. What the `index` tells you is where you are horizontally on the grid. The `stride` tells you how long each row is, think of it as an offset.

So inside your kernel you'll have a loop like this:

```
for (int i = index; i < sizeOfYourData; i += stride)
{
    // [...]
}
```

This tells you exactly what thread you're working on. The rest is trivial. The variable `i` is now your "thread id", you can use it as an offset to your buffer to allow each thread to access a different portion of it.

So you'll want something like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(int fileSize, unsigned char * buffer)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for (int i3 = index; i3 < (1L << 41); i3 += stride)
    {
        deCipher(buffer, i3, fileSize);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. Indeed, I'm not very comfortable with parallel programming concepts on GPUs. But, I'm going to try to get more information on the subject.